Is there a way to resolve the issue of resolution changing the size and position of my macro buttons?
I spent a long time making an excel workbook that uses macro buttons and its important to me that the buttons stay the same size and in the same position. However, every time I view the workbook on my desktop (instead of my laptop), the buttons distort and move around.
I've changed the properties of the shape and even of the document so that nothing should get resized or reshaped, but it still occurs. A colleague of mine said it may be due to the resolution.
My question is, is there a work around for this? a way to stop the resolution differences from affecting the position of the buttons and the shape.
I even wondered if there was some VBA code that might help?

Welcome to SO. Without any example it's difficult to reproduce your problem and answer. But resolution indeed may affect. Anyways, buttons should stay in the same cell even i the resolution changes. Do the buttons move out of their original column too?

Probably you are using ActiveX-Buttons? The size-Issue is one (of many) reason that I no longer use them. For Buttons, I usually use a Rectangle, format it (eg setting shadow, set backcolor to gray...) and assign a macro to it.

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thank you for your reply! Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question, I'm rather new to this. So my buttons don't move out of their cell but they stretch and the buttons getter slightly further apart or overlap. I swapped to shapes and assigned a macro and i had the same issue with them.

@FunThomas Thank you for your reply! I tried this too but I had the same issue.

Discussion of check boxes moving around here
